# Unital commutative dual Banach *-algebras whose $w^*$-closed ideals are principal

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-algebras

Let $A$ be a  commutative Banach *-algebra. For a given  ideal $I$ of $A$, we say that, it is principal if there is a projection $p$  (i.e. $p^2=p=p^*$) in $A$   with $I=Ap$.

> Q. Any characterization of dual commutative Banach *-algebras whose $w^*$-closed ideals are all principal?

Comment: Those commutative unital dual Banach *-algebras are the ones in which every weak$^*$ closed left ideal is a complemented subspace.

Comment: The word "left" is redundant if you are only considering commutative algebras

Comment: @OnurOktay Your claim does not seem to be correct, since in general complementation as a Banach subspace does not ensure algebraic properties. Consider the two dimensional commutative algebra $\left\{ \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & a \end{pmatrix} a,b \in {\bf C} \right\}$.

Comment: @YemonChoi Thanks for pointing out the oversight. It should read: *"Those unital dual Banach *-algebras are the ones in which every weak$^*$ closed left ideal is complemented as a subspace (thus as a left module) by another weak$^*$ closed left ideal."*

Comment: I guess this is motivated by the fact the condition _does_ hold for a commutative von Neumann algebra?  If the condition holds for a general $A$, then in particular every ideal must be self-adjoint.  Do you know which commutative dual Banach $*$-algebras satisfy this (weaker) condition?